# Preserve ordering with immutable Map?

Tags: java, collections

When using `java.util.Map.of()`, it does *not* preserve ordering. Is there a way to have immutable `Map` which does preserve ordering?

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are looking for is [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).
Linked Hashmap is a like a regular HashMap that preserves insertion order.

Comment: I know LinkedHashMap, however,  I need simple immutable Map. Map.of("a", "b") would be ideal, however, it does not preserve ordering as I see..

Comment: Use `map = Collections.immutableMap(map)` to make it immutable.

Comment: You might have to create you own data structure :/ I'd take a look at Java's Entry<k,v> class

Comment: I found `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` would be the same as `immutableMap`?

Comment: @nimo23 `Map.of("a", "b")` is a bad example, as there is no ordering for a single entry. `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` produces a *wrapper* which does not allow modification by its interface, but can’t prevent modifications through a reference to the wrapped map. If you construct such a map and ensure, that no other references to the `LinkedHashMap` exist, you have a de-facto immutable map. That’s the best you can get when you need specific properties, like an order, as no-one is going to mirror all implementation types with a truly immutable version.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

Make a `LinkedHashMap`, wrap with a call to [`Collections.umodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)), as discussed in [*Unmodifiable View Collections*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodview).

## `Map.of` unmodifiable static factory maps

The [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementation used by `Map.of` methods is clearly documented in the Javadoc. One of the bullet points makes clear that the keys are not sorted:

> Unmodifiable Maps
>
> …
>
> The iteration order of mappings is unspecified and is subject to change.
>
> …

So you must use another implementation of `Map` if need sorting.

## `SortedMap`

By "preserve order" did you mean sorted order?

Java includes the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface to define behavior of `Map` implementations that maintain a total ordering across all its keys.

There are two such implementations bundled with Java: [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

## Original insertion order preserved

Your Question is not clear, but I would guess that what you meant by "preserve ordering" is that you want the key maintained in the order in which they where added to the map. [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) does just that, as mentioned in the [correct Answer by randypaq13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58019496/642706).

To quote the Javadoc:

> … predictable iteration order …
>
> … maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

## Unmodifiable maps

The `LinkedHashMap` meets your need for original-insertion-order, but not your need for being unmodifiable. For that, use the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html) class with its utility method [`unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)).

```
Map< String , String > map = new LinkedHashMap<>() ;
map.put( "this" , "that" ) ;
map.put( "other" , "thing" ) ;
Map< String , String > unmodMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap( map ) ;
```

Be sure to study the documentation on [Unmodifiable View Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodview) to understand their behavior. Click to zoom.

---

Here is a table giving an overview of all the `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Comment: `new LinkedHashMap (Map.of ( "dog" , "bark" , "cat" , "meow" ))`  won't give the desired result, since the order gets jumbled by `Map.of`.

Comment: There are some things with the table, I’d improve. “order of keys” is misleading, as the entire map is ordered, as the `entrySet()` and `values()` views reflect the order too. I’d use “order of entries” or just “order”. There is no benefit in distinguishing between `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap`. The latter is what the former should have been in the first place but had to be delivered as extending interface, as interface evolution is problematic when there might be 3rd party implementations. Further, I’d put “immutable” into the “concurrent” column where applicable…

Comment: @Holger Thank you very much for feedback. I'm modifying the chart now. (a) changed to "iteration order" to match the Javadoc. (b) As for the sub-interfaces, they are what they are, so I want to expose them as such. I did add an inheritance chart, noting each version of Java. (c) You lost me on the last point – none of the listed classes are immutable.

Comment: Well, it’s striking that there is no implementation of `SortedMap` that isn’t also a `NavigableMap`. So a single “sorted/navigable” column would be sufficient. The implementations returned by `Map.of` are specified to be immutable and that’s in the list. Further, `Hashtable` has all of its method `synchronized`, which is a policy worth being mentioned in the “concurrent” column. As a minor suggestion, I’d place special-purpose implementations like `WeakHashMap` at the end of the list, before the legacy implementation `Hashtable`, but after all others (you may add `IdentityHashMap` there too)…

Comment: @Holger Thank you again for all your suggestions. I've modified my diagram, after considering your points. Doing this diagram has inspired me to write a talk reviewing the various `Map` implementations bundled with Java. So your input has proven useful there too.

Answer (score 4):

The following does NOT preserve ordering:

```
Map.of("a", 1, "b", 2);
```

If you want to have an **immutable ordered** `Map`, then you must go this roundabout way:

```
var map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", 2);
map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
```

Not very optimal, because you have to create two maps, one for the ordering and the other for being immutable..

Comment: This is currently probably the best way to do what you want to do, and indeed it’s less convenient than `Map.of`. Note however that the unmodifiable Map is just a wrapper around the original map. It doesn’t copy or store the elements itself.

Answer (score 1):

If Google Guava already exists in your project then
[`ImmutableMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#method.summary) will please your needs.

1. Immutability (not an unmodifiable view) and
2. Iteration order = creation order

More about [ImmutableCollection](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) types.